# React native api fetch don’t get parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

I have a problem with my react native code , 
I’m trying to fetch data from an api url, and i do multiple calls. So i get the data but my last call don’t work , i need the data from the previous calls and pass it to my method but that don’t work. The method is launched by a button with onpress, if i press one the parameters are null but if i press a second time i get the parameters.

Here is my code :

```
_getResults() {
this.setState({ isLoading: true })
defaultStops().then(data => {
  this.setState({ 
    stops: data.data,
    isLoading : false
   })
})
getDepStop(this.depStop).then(data => {
  this.setState({ 
    depStop: data.data[0].name,
    depStopId: data.data[0].id,
    isLoading : false
   })
})
getArrStop(this.arrStop, this.state.depStopId).then(data => {
  this.setState({ 
    arrStop: data.data[0].name,
    arrStopId: data.data[0].id,
    isLoading : false
   })
})
getCompany(this.state.depStopId, this.state.depStop, this.state.arrStopId, this.state.arrStop, this.date).then(data => {
  this.setState({ 
    company: data,
    isLoading : false
   })
})
}
```

Its the getCompany method who don’t get the parameters all previous methods are working .

Here is my api call :

```
export function defaultStops () {
const url = 'https://www.APIURL.com/api/stops/departure?lang=fr'
return fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.catch((error) => console.error(error))
}

export function getDepStop (text) {
const url = 'https://www.APIURL.com/api/stops/departure?lang=fr&term=' + text + '&q=' + text
return fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.catch((error) => console.error(error))
}

export function getArrStop (text, depStopId) {
const url = 'https://www.APIURL.com/api/stops/arrival?lang=fr&q=' + text + '&stopId=' + depStopId
return fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.catch((error) => console.error(error))
}

export function getCompany (depStopId, depStopName, arrStopId, arrStopName, date) {
const url = 'https://www.APIURL.com/api/routes?id=1&depStopId='+depStopId+'&depStopName='+depStopName+'&arrStopId='+arrStopId+'&arrStopName='+arrStopName+'&dateFrom='+date+'&type=bus&currency=EUR'
return fetch(url)
.then((response) => response)
.catch((error) => console.error(error))
}

export function getTicket (depStopId, arrStopId, stopExtDep, stopExtArr, date, companyId) {
const url = 'https://APIURL/api/prices?companyId='+ companyId +'&stopExtDep='+ stopExtDep +'&stopExtArr='+ stopExtArr +'&stopIdDep='+ depStopId +'&stopIdArr='+ arrStopId +'&dateFrom='+ date +'&dateTo=&currency=EUR&k=cbapp'
return fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.catch((error) => console.error(error))
}
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Data fetching will work asyc so you have to call the other api in then of first api and setstate doesnt update immediately you have to use callback parameter of setstate if you want to do something after setting state

Comment: How to use callback parameters in my method ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate . Docs to use setstate callback

Comment: When i try to put my last method as a callback i get an error: can’t call sestate on an unmounted component.

Comment: Ok sorry it was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was to use a callback after my setState :

```
getArrStop(this.arrStop, this.state.depStopId).then(data => {
  this.setState({ 
    arrStop: data.data[0].name,
    arrStopId: data.data[0].id,
    isLoading : false
   },function(){getCompany(this.state.depStopId, this.state.depStop, this.state.arrStopId, this.state.arrStop, this.date).then(data => {
    this.setState({ 
      company: data,
      isLoading : false
     })
  })})
})
```